Jetclient making calls to a local DDEV server. Setting up SPA, domain issues
I'm building an APi in Laravel for a future front end (react) to talk to and handle all queries (inc user management)
this is largely working.
Now I want to set up 2FA via Fortify.
I'm having auth issues even after following the docs.
I think it's related to the 'allowed' domains that are talking to the Api.
So my question:
If I'm in JetClient making calls to my DDev assigned URL (and that all works for current routes, both sanctum auth and no auth).
Fortity needs to know where the requests are expected from.
How can I discover what my load IP.URL is that jetclient tells the Api?
I need to allow that traffic past the auth and it's never working.
What is my jetLCient local IP address (I've tried 127.0.0.1, localhost but these don't seem to get through the auth process.

Where does your jetClient execute? Inside the web container? In a browser? What URL is it hitting?

If the jetClient is executing in the browser, and is communicating with your PHP app inside the container, it may appear to come from host.docker.internal. But the way to debug this is to create simple PHP code that looks at the headers on a normal request.
